# Prompting a user to quit or continue

Tags: python, math, input, prompt

I am trying to write a code that prompts a user to choose a function or to quit. I want it to keep prompting them until they type in 'quit' or 'exit' (any form i.e. all caps or all lowercase). I can't seem to figure out how to get it to run. Any tips?

```
import math

prompt = '''Enter a number for the function you want to execute.
        Type 'exit' or 'quit' to terminate.
1 sin(x)
2 cos(x)
3 tan(x)
4 asin(x)
5 acos(x)
6 atan(x)
7 ln(x)
8 sqrt(x)
9 factorial(x)
:'''

while True:
    function = input(prompt)

    if function == 'quit' or 'exit':
        break
    elif function(range(0,10)):
        print(f"You entered {function()}!")
    else:
        print("Answer not valid try again")

functions = {1: math.sin, 2: math.cos, 3: math.tan, 4: math.asin,
             5: math.acos, 6: math.atan, 7: math.log, 8: math.sqrt, 9: math.factorial}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is here:

```
if function == 'quit' or 'exit':
```

Python breaks this conditional into `if function == 'quit'` and `if 'exit'`, and will break if either is true. `if 'exit'` will always be true, because you aren't comparing anything and `'exit'` is not an empty string. You should change this line to:

```
if function in ['quit', 'exit']:
```

This tests if `function` is in the list, and breaks if it is.

---

Once you make that change, your code will still have errors. It's not clear if you want to run the function that the user selects, or tell them which function they selected. You should clear up your question as much as you can, or ask another one.

Answer (score 0):

`if 'exit'` returns `True` as it is a non-empty string.

```
>>> bool('')
False
>>> bool('exit')
True
```

This means you're calling `break` every single iteration, as `exit` is always `True`.

The other issue you also have, is by default `input()` stores a `string` value. In your use-case, you're trying to return both integers and strings.

On the line `function(range(0,10)):` you're going to get a `TypeError`.

```
test = '1'
```

> test(range(0,10))
>
> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> >       File "", line 1, in 
> >         test(range(0,10))
> >
> > TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Even after fixing this `TypeError` you will get a return of `False` as a `string` will not exist in a `range()` value.

```
bool(test in range (0, 10))
#False
```

We can address the issues by adjusting your code to the below, please refer to the comments for information on what each line does.

```
run = True #We will run our loop based on the value of run
terminate = ['quit', 'exit'] #Prompt termination words

while run:
    function = input(prompt)

    # If the value stored in function is a NOT a digit Example: 'quit' AND the word exists in our terminate queries.

    if function.isdigit() is False and function in terminate:

        # Break the loop by setting run to False

        run = False

    # Else if, the valye stored in function IS a digit Example: '1' AND it is between 1-9

    elif function.isdigit() and 9 >= int(function) > 0:
        print(f"You entered {function}!")
    else:
        print("Invalid Answer, try again.")
```